# Fast query come to slow log [mysql]

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, mysql-slow-query-log

Sometimes I see in slow log, query which should not be there.

I know such query(ies) execute many times per day and it is fast enough, when I analyze slow log I see that this particular query droped to log only at once,

```
### 1 Query 
### Total time: 23.728427, Average time: 23.728427
### Taking 23.728427  seconds to complete
### Rows analyzed 349012
```

does it means that it became slow because some table was locked ? or some another query was make DB server busy ? or something else ???

How to figure out why, definitely fast query came to the log ?

Comment: If that particular query runs fast enough normally, you're just seeing the effects of a busy database.

Comment: @MortenJensen Then how I can figure out what exactly makes my DB so busy ?

Comment: Well for one, try checking the server statistics. How many queries are you serving pr. second? What is the average completion time pr query. You need to profile each request to be absolutely certain where you need to look. Determining server load can only be done with detailed profiling